# What does string::npos mean?

Tags: c++

what does the following statement mean?

```
    string s="Joe Alan Smith"";
    cout << (s.find("Allen") == string::npos) << endl;
```

Answer (score 15):

Actually `string::find()` returns the position of the found string, but if it doesn't find the given string, it returns `string::npos`, where `npos` means **no position**.

`npos` is an unsigned integral value, Standard defines it to be `-1` (signed representation) which denotes no position.

```
//npos is unsigned, that is why cast is needed to make it signed!
cout << (signed int) string::npos <<endl;
```

Output:

-1

See at Ideone : http://www.ideone.com/VRHUj

Comment: The value isn't implementation-defined; the standard specifies that it is `string::size_type(-1)`.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks. Mentioned this in my answer!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

> As a return value it is usually used to indicate failure.

In other words, print out if the string 'Allen' was not found in the given string `s`.

Answer (score 2):

The `.find()` method returns `string::npos` if it did not find the target string within the searched string. It is an integer whose value cannot represent a "found" index value, usually -1. A valid index value is an integer >= 0 which represents the index at which the target string was found.